# Unity3D 5.4.1 - Can I get object transformations at different times from animation?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, export, transformation

I'm trying to export levels created in Unity for a school project, and I would like to export a path that the player will fly along. My plan was to create an animation and store positions along the path and then export the transformation values at those points (or possibly at intermediate points on the curve as well), however I can't figure out how to extract the object transformations at a certain point in the animation. Is this at all possible? Could I for example animate the gameobject in code and pick out the transformations at some interval or something? I have been done a lot of googling, but I've not really found a clear answer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible using [Animation events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html). Write a method to record the data you want at various points in the animation timeline. Be advised though there is [some arguement](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=unity%20animation%20events%20not%20firing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=KtD3V_msK-nR8gfn64HoDQ) as to whether this is reliable. An alternative would be to use coroutines to report the data you're after after some time period according to when you want the animations to yield data. Edit: hey look at me I used 'after after' legitimately in a sentence :)